# MySQL sum case value equals max value of that group

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve this query to return the total count of items in a group and **the total of items in that group which value equals the max value of one field of that group** and also which is the max(value).

So far:

```
SELECT
    limid, COUNT(*), SUM(CASE WHEN cotavertical=MAX(cotavertical) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), MAX(cotavertical)
FROM limites
LEFT JOIN tbparentchild ON parent=limid
LEFT JOIN tbspatialbi ON child=rgi
WHERE limtipo=4 AND x=1
GROUP BY limid
```

So far MySQL returns

> "Invalid use of group function."

Is it too complex to solve in MySQL only? Better to use algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the max value for each group in an aggregate function (`SUM`) before the aggregation has finished, and hence it is not available.  The query below uses the strategy of joining a subquery which contains the max value of `cotavertical` for each `limid` group.  In this case, the max value per group which you want to use will now be available from another source, and you can sum using it.

```
SELECT l.limid,
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN cotavertical = t.cotamax THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       MAX(cotavertical)
FROM limites l
LEFT JOIN tbparentchild pc
    ON pc.parent = l.limid
LEFT JOIN tbspatialbi s
    ON pc.child = s.rgi
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT limid, MAX(cotavertical) AS cotamax
    FROM limites
    LEFT JOIN tbparentchild
        ON parent = limid
    LEFT JOIN tbspatialbi
        ON child = rgi
    WHERE limtipo = 4 AND x = 1
    GROUP BY limid
) t
    ON l.limid = t.limid
WHERE limtipo = 4 AND l.x = 1
GROUP BY l.limid
```

Another option for solving your problem would be to use a subquery directly in the `CASE` statement.  But, given the size and number of joins in your original query, this would be *way* uglier than the query above.  MySQL does not support common table expressions, which would have helped with both these solutions.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Just one note that on the outside `where` I've put `l.x` to avoid ambiguity.